# How to import datetime columns from csv to Postgres

Tags: postgresql

First timer. I am trying to import a datetime csv column into postgreSQL using the `import/export` button, but it is not recognizing the column. This is the message I get:

**ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "31/10/2020 19:39"**
**HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.**

Is there a way to change the datastyle format and what datastyle format am I looking at?

Thank you!

Comment: In `psql` do `show datastyle`. I'm guessing it will return something like `ISO, MDY`, where `MDY` is the date ordering Month/Date/Year. You need to change this at least temporarily  by doing `set datestyle = 'iso, dmy';`. This will only work for the current session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the [Import CSV File Into PostgreSQL Table](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/) tutorial as a basis, and changing the file `persons.csv` to:

```
First Name,Last Name,Date Of Birth,Email
John,Doe,31/01/1995 11:30,john.doe@postgresqltutorial.com
Jane,Doe,05/02/1995 23:30,jane.doe@postgresqltutorial.com
```

with `DateStyle` defined as `ISO, DMY`, I had no problems importing the file, as shown below:

```
halley=> SET DateStyle TO ISO, DMY;
SET
halley=> SHOW DateStyle;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, DMY
(1 registro)

halley=> CREATE TABLE persons (
halley(>   id SERIAL,
halley(>   first_name VARCHAR(50),
halley(>   last_name VARCHAR(50),
halley(>   dob TIMESTAMP,
halley(>   email VARCHAR(255),
halley(>   PRIMARY KEY (id)
halley(> );
CREATE TABLE
halley=> COPY persons(first_name, last_name, dob, email)
halley-> FROM '/home/halley/Downloads/persons.csv'
halley-> DELIMITER ','
halley-> CSV HEADER;
COPY 2
halley=> SELECT * FROM persons;
 id | first_name | last_name |         dob         |              email              
----+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------------------
  1 | John       | Doe       | 1995-01-31 11:30:00 | john.doe@postgresqltutorial.com
  2 | Jane       | Doe       | 1995-02-05 23:30:00 | jane.doe@postgresqltutorial.com
(2 registros)
```

It seems that the only problem is really the style of the date. I hope this has helped.